# R-S configuration or Cahn-Ingold-Prelog configuration

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry, chirality

How to assign R and S configurations in alkenes and more complicated structures ?

I know that the groups attached to the sp3 hybridized carbon is first prioritized by atomic number then we see the next set of atoms in the unassigned groups.

But it is said that groups containing double or triple bonds are assigned priorities as if they are duplicated or triplicated. What does this means ?

Comment: My suggestion - Google for "cip rules double and triple bonds" - you will find more examples than anybody here can list.

Answer (score 1):

Duplicated means that if there is double bond between say C and O then consider that two O are  linked to C through single bond and with that O two C are linked to it each.
The following figure will help more.
[image]